# Has open source ever created a single file database that auto handles transactions?

Tags: database, firebird

Has open source ever created a **single file database** that has better performance when handling large sets of sql queries that aren't delivered in formal SQL transaction sets?   I work with a .NET server that does some heavy replication of thousands of rows of data from another server and it does so it a 1-by-1 fashion without formal SQL transactions.  So, therefore I cannot use SQLite or FirebirdDB or JavaDB because they all don't automatically batch the transactions and therefore the performance is dismal.   Each insert waits for the success of the previous one, etc.  So, I am forced to use a heavier database like SQLServer, MySQL, Postgres, or Oracle.

Does anyone know of a flat file database (that has a JDBC connect driver) that would support auto batching transactions and solve my problem?

The main think I dont like about the heavier databases is the lack of the ability to see inside the database with a one-mouse-click operation, like you can with SQLLite.

> I tried creating a SQLite database and
>   then set PRAGMA read_uncommitted=TRUE;
>   and it didn't result in any
>   performance improvement.

Comment: "Open source" whoever that is ;-) has created a minimum of `three` solutions for even the most out-of-mainstream need; but some of these may be in a state of abandon of disrepair.  (I'm not poo-pooing OS in any way, this high ratio of of "waste" is part of the -great- deal).  More to the point, rather than locating a odd dbms, why not implementing a thin layer atop one of the ones you mention, to introduce this batching feature?  In this fashion you solve the problem while keeping a well known system.

Comment: Hopefully, Open Source will see this question and answer it. :)

Comment: Bear in mind that, if you have odd needs in Open Source software, you can always fix them for yourself, which is an advantage over proprietary software.

Comment: We have no plans to build such a database right now. Please refer to the suggestions made below.

Answer (score 3):

I think that [Firebird](https://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) can work for this.

Firebird have good dotnet provider and many solution for [replication](https://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq249/)

May be you can read this [article for Firebird transaction](https://web.archive.org/web/20231015050343/https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_22)

Answer (score 1):

Try hypersonic DB - http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch02.html#N104FC

Answer (score 0):

If you want your transactions to be durable (i.e. survive a power failure) then the database will HAVE to write to the disc after each transaction (this is usually a log of some sort).

If your transactions are very small this will result in a huge number of writes, and very poor performance even on your battery backed raid controller or SSD, but worse performance on consumer-grade hardware.

The only way of avoiding this is to somehow disable the flush at txn commit (which of course breaks durability). I have no idea which ones support this, but it should be easy to find out.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  maybe ill try this:  http://www.uic.edu/depts/accc/systems/berkeley-db.doc/api_tcl/txn_commit.html